# How does '::' at the beginning of the class affect scope (ruby/rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, inheritance

I'm working in a large rails project where I have some files:

**app/services/my_service/my_action/my_model_2.rb**:

```
module <my_service>
  module <my_action>
    class <my_model_2>
      . . .
      if some_var = <my_model>::MY_CONST
      if some_Var = ::<my_model>::MY_CONST # <-- what is the difference here?
```

**app/services/my_service/my_action/my_model.rb**:

```
module <my_service>
  module <my_action>
    class <my_model>
```

**app/services/my_service/my_model.rb**:

```
module <my_service>
    class <my_model>
```

**app/models/my_model.rb**:

```
class <my_model> < ActiveRecord::Base
  . . . 
  MY_CONST = "my constant"
```

What is the difference in my_model_2.rb?

How would I scope correctly to access each of the models from my_model_2.rb?

Note that app/models class name is the same as app/services class name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leading `::` forces the Ruby interpreter to start resolving the class name from the top level namespace. That means, in case you have a class `Foo::Bar::Baz` and the `Boo` class/module defined in both

- Foo::Boo
- Boo

Referencing `Boo` inside `Foo::Bar::Baz` will actually end up to the `Foo::Boo` module/class, whereas if you use `::Boo` it will match the `Boo` because the resolution of the name will start from the main namespace.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for.